# Using Studio Flow is there a way to put the existing call into a conference, then add another caller?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flow

I am trying to place two callers into a conference using Studio Flow. I know how to place the original caller into a conference, but the flow pauses until a call termination event occurs.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to add the current caller to a conference, then dial and add a second caller to the conference within Flow, or is an external function necessary?
2. Is there a way to implement hangupOnStar for the original caller since they're the in control of the call (they would use "*" codes to perform additional options during the call)?